# LINQ Sort Numeric Data Only But Retain The List Intact

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have the following program. My data types are all string. From the list I want to sort those entries that have numeric values. Those entries without numeric data will be always on the last items. Here's my code. Please help.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "John",   Position = "100" });
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Peter",  Position = "78"  });
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Larry",  Position = "NA"  });
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Lovely", Position = ""    });
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Rose",   Position = "50"  });
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Drew",   Position = "34"  });

        //Help me do the sorting for position that is a number. Priority in sorting are positions which are numbers
        var sortedPersons = persons.OrderBy(x=>double.Parse(x.Position)).ToList();
        foreach (var person in sortedPersons)
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Position: {1}", person.Name, person.Position);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

Based on my sample, I want to sort the items as

1. Drew
2. Rose
3. Peter
4. John
5. Lovely
6. Larry

(for Lovely and Larry it doesn't matter for me how they are sorted as long as I got sorted correctly Drew to John).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `.TryParse()` instead, and assign max value to anything that can't be parsed

You can either use `double.MaxValue` or `double.PositiveInfinity` as default value. The latter is the greater of the two.

```
persons.OrderBy(x => double.TryParse(x.Position, out double d) ? d : double.PositiveInfinity)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a custom [`IComparer<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) and pass its instance as the second argument to [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__) method

```cs
public class PositionComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        double xValue = int.TryParse(x, out var xParsed) ? xParsed : double.PositiveInfinity;
        double yValue = int.TryParse(y, out var yParsed) ? yParsed : double.PositiveInfinity;

        return xValue.CompareTo(yValue);
    }
}
```

Example of the usage

```cs
var sortedPersons = persons.OrderBy(x => x.Position, new PositionComparer()).ToList();
```

It provides a correct order and allows you to reuse this code for comparison of such values in other places of your code.

```
Name: Drew, Position: 34
Name: Rose, Position: 50
Name: Peter, Position: 78
Name: John, Position: 100
Name: Larry, Position: NA
Name: Lovely, Position:
```

IMO, it's also easier to understand, maintain and debug, than `Linq` methods and predicates

Comment: If `Position` appears to be `"2147483647"` (which is `int.MaxValue`) it be cosidered to be equal to any nin-numeric value (like `"bla-bla-bla"`). So we can well have `"bla-bla-bla", "2147483647", "non-numeric"` order

Comment: @DmitryBychenko OP states that _For Lovely and Larry it doesn't matter for me how they are sorted_ So, order of non-numeric items doesn't matter

Comment: `persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Rose", Position = "2147483647" });` makes `Rose` to be *equal* to *any* `Person` with non-numeric `Position`

Comment: switching to `float` or `double` parsing and using infinity will easily solve this issue, OP didn't mentioned any edge cases here

Comment: Yes, `double xValue = int.TryParse(x, out var xParsed) ? xParsed : double.PositiveInfinity;` (same for `yValue`) will solve the edge case

Comment: This solution requires a dedicated class and looks like "old fashioned" C# but at least I find it easy to understand, debug, and maintain compared to other approaches relying on LINQ predicates and Tuples.

Comment: @AFract yes, that's the main point. You can also reuse it (if needed, of course) for comparison in other methods instead of repeating a parsing logic inside linq methods every time

Answer (score 1):

If `Position` must be a valid `int` (say, `Position = "7.83e+1"` considered to be *not numeric* and should be in the *end of the list*) we can sort by *tuple*:

```
  var sortedPersons = persons
    .OrderBy(item => (!int.TryParse(item.Position, out var v), v))
    .ToList();
```

Here, we sort first by tuple's `Item1` which detrmine if `item.Position` is `int` or not:

```
!int.TryParse(item.Position, out int v)
```

so the valid integers *comes first*. Then we sort by tuple's `Item2` which is *parsed value*

```
v
```

to have `Position`s ordered. If `Position` should be `double` (say, `Position = "-7.83e-10"` is *perfectly valid*) you can either use *Innat3's* solution or change `int` to `double`:

```
  var sortedPersons = persons
    .OrderBy(item => (!double.TryParse(item.Position, out var v), v))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var sortedPersons = persons.Where(x => int.TryParse(x.Position, out int res))
                           .OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Position))
                           .Concat(persons.Where(x => ! int.TryParse(x.Position, out int res)));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit more, so others and people who are not to familiar with the language understand whats going on?